# Which one I should go for, ADATA SP550 120GB vs Samsung EVO 120GB SSD's?

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

I'm new to SSD, After doing some research i end up with 2 models ADATA SP550 120GB and Samsung EVO 120GB. ADATA seems to be a TLC NAND Flash which is low in endurance but i have no idea about EVO(Could be TLC/MLC). But both are of 3-bit/cell flash memory. Please suggest me a good one.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. 3 bit/cell and TLC mean the same thing. Samsung has more than one EVO, the 840 and the 850. What are your requirements and budget?

Comment: I'm looking for good Performance and Reliable disk under 4000 INR (~60$ USD). If both have same endurance level then I can go for Adata rite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going for Samsung SSD 850 EVO.

After some research I found ADATA's TLC is a poor performer. In real world tests the file transfer read speed was decent, but the write speed tests would bring the SP550 to its knees. Sequential write is averaged about 50 MB/s, where as Samsung 850 EVO is able to maintain so much better performance.

We can push our self to spend extra bucks to get a quality product.

Answer (score 2):

The Samsung is much more durable since all the components are manufactured in house and they have very strict quality control. They are both TLC, but the Samsung has a really good TLC flash chip. The Samsung SSD is also much faster than the ADATA.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung all day, every day. Their warranty is amazing and the speeds are all at the top of the charts. I've installed several Evos and Pros in systems and have been nothing but thrilled with the results, especially in older systems.